# Does database backup contain the user's GRANT, REVOKE and DENY permissions?

Tags: sql-server, backup, migration

I am migrating database to another SQL server.

I have scripted the logins from the source server and migrated them into the target server. Also, I have backedup the source db and restored it on target db.

Does database backup contain the user's GRANT, REVOKE and DENY permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does, yes, including fine grained permissions controlled via row level security.

You can confirm by inspecting the information exposed by [sys.database_permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-permissions-transact-sql)

Comment: Then why does microsoft ask to script this for migration (reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/manage-metadata-when-making-a-database-available-on-another-server?view=sql-server-ver15#grant-revoke-and-deny-permissions-on-system-objects)

Comment: That is referencing system object permissions that are controlled by information in the `master` databases, not those set/removed for objects in your database via GRANT/REVOKE/DENY in that database.

Comment: I'm confused as to what is the meaning of `system object permissions` can you help me by clarifying whether the system object means permissions of the master database or does it mean user database permissions that are held in master database? If it is the later, then what is an example of this please?

Comment: From the documentation you linked to “Permissions on system objects such as stored procedures, extended stored procedures, functions, and views, are stored in the master database and must be configured on the destination server instance”. If it isn't in your database, i.e. things in master/msdb/etc., then those objects and any related permissions won't be transferred in a backup of your database restored to another SQL Server instance.

Comment: What is the way to identify and transfer these?

Comment: Again, the documentation you linked to gives the information needed to get the information: query master.sys.database_permissions and related system views. But you probably do not want this copying over with your database as they are by definition system level. Your database users probably do not need and do not have system level permissions.

Comment: Does differential and log backup also contain the db level users, role membership and securable permission changes?

Comment: If an entity is included in a full backup, then changes to it will be included in diff and log backups, so yes for the database level permissions & memberships but no for instance level ones. You can test this easily by creating a DB with a mix of users/memberships/perms, following backup procedures, and restoring to a different instance. Developer edition is free so you can spin up test instances as needed without licensing/cost issues.